# Create thumbnail for three.js scene

Tags: javascript, django, three.js

I am building a website to visualize biological neurons of animals.
I have a list of all the neurons names in a list and I draw the neuron with THREE JS when the user presses it's name.
The problem is that I have several hundreds of neurons and the names don't give any estimation about the shape so the user has to press every neuron until he finds what he is looking for. 
Can I (automatically) create thumbnails for the rendering of each neuron and show it beside the neuron name?
I am thinking about a way that allows me to go through all the neurons list and render them virtually (without showing them) and create thumbnails for every one and then save these images.
Is this possible to be done automatically?

I have seen the [Screen shots by THREE JS](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/09/03/screenshot-in-javascript/) but it requires the P button to be hit and it generates a screen shot and opens it in a new tab and doesn't save it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me https://github.com/khaledalyawad/node-threejs-thumbnailer
You can generate thumbnails from a local file or from a url

`renderUrl`
`renderFile`